# Is it possible to make nginx cache expires at certain time?

Tags: nginx, cache

So basically what I want to do is make nginx's cache expires at 24:00 everyday. I know I could use tools like  nginx-cache-purge or just manually delete cache files on disk, but I prefer to letting nginx handle this itself. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [proxy_cache_purge](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_purge) direction where you can use an access point to purge cache.

Then you can use `curl` inside your cron job and execute that at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `X-Accel-Expires` header on your application reponse with value "@epoch" to set an absolute time in seconds since Epoch, up to which the response may be cached.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_valid
So for example with BSD `date` you could use result of `date -j -v23H -v59M -v59S +"@%s"` for X-Accel-Expires header or any similar function with programming language you use.